# Push Notification using REST API in outlook

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, python-3.7, microsoft-graph-webhooks

I tried to get subscription for push notification

Here is the code

```
`def subscribe(access_token):
  url = graph_endpoint.format('/subscriptions')
  d = {"changeType": "updated","notificationUrl": 
       "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient","resource": 
       "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages","clientState": 
       "secretClientValue","latestSupportedTlsVersion": 
       "v1_2"}
  r = make_api_call('POST',url, access_token,payload= d)`
```

the response code was 400

the access token is correct

and another doubt is how to make a login in outlook webhook ???
If any body know the step by step to create a push notification in outlook please share....

Comment: What permissions did you request/get with the token? What error message do you get in the response?

Comment: elif (method.upper() == 'POST'):
      headers.update({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' })
      response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = json.dumps(payload))

Comment: I'm not sure this replies to my questions